# avoiding callback hell losing variable scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and I'm having problems trying to aboid callback hell.
Now I'm developing an endpoitn to register users in a mongo database, the problem I'm facig is that I lose the acces to some variables if I modularize the function where they are used.

The code:

Working callback hell:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    dbserver = 'mongodb://localhost/',
    dbname = 'authdb';


mongoose.connect(dbserver + dbname);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('connectet to mongo db: ' + dbname);
})



userModel = require('./user.js');



function singIn (req, res){

    var email = req.body.email,
    name = req.body.name,
    secondName  = req.body.secondName,
    pass = req.body.pass,
    bday = req.body.bday;

    var user = new userModel.user();

    user.Email = email;
    user.Name = name;
    user.SecondName = secondName;
    user.Pass.Hash = pass;
    user.BirthDate = bday;



    db.model('user').find({Email : email},function (err,foundUsers){

    if(!err && foundUsers.length === 0){

        user.save(function (err, users){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send("Not inserted");

    }else{
            console.log(user);
            console.log('registered!');
            res.send("OKish");
    }
});
    }else{
        console.log(err);
        console.log(foundUsers);

        res.send("Not inserted");
    }

});

};


exports.singIn  = singIn;
```

Not working modularized

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    dbserver = 'mongodb://localhost/',
    dbname = 'authdb';


mongoose.connect(dbserver + dbname);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('connectet to mongo db: ' + dbname);
})



userModel = require('./user.js');



function singIn (req, res){

    var email = req.body.email,
    name = req.body.name,
    secondName  = req.body.secondName,
    pass = req.body.pass,
    bday = req.body.bday;

    var user = new userModel.user();

    user.Email = email;
    user.Name = name;
    user.SecondName = secondName;
    user.Pass.Hash = pass;
    user.BirthDate = bday;



    db.model('user').find({Email : email},addUser);

};


function saveUser(err, users){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send("Not inserted");

    }else{
            console.log(user);
            console.log('registered!');
            res.send("OKish");
    }
}

function addUser(err,foundUsers){

    if(!err && foundUsers.length === 0){

        user.save(SaveUser);
    }else{
        console.log(err);
        console.log(foundUsers);

        res.send("Not inserted");
    }

}   




exports.singIn  = singIn;
```

The problem here is that in the second snippet I can't acces the variables res and user in the functions addUser and saveUser.

Is there any way to get both variables in the scope of the functions or I have to bear whit the callback hell this time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the `saveUser` and `addUser` functions within the context `signIn` so that they have access to its parameters and local variables:

```
function signIn (req, res){    
    var email = req.body.email,
    name = req.body.name,
    secondName  = req.body.secondName,
    pass = req.body.pass,
    bday = req.body.bday;

    var user = new userModel.user();    
    user.Email = email;
    user.Name = name;
    user.SecondName = secondName;
    user.Pass.Hash = pass;
    user.BirthDate = bday;

    db.model('user').find({Email : email},addUser);

    function saveUser(err, users){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send("Not inserted");
        }else{
            console.log(user);
            console.log('registered!');
            res.send("OKish");
        }
    }

    function addUser(err,foundUsers){
        if(!err && foundUsers.length === 0){
            user.save(saveUser);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
            console.log(foundUsers);
            res.send("Not inserted");
        }
    }       
};
```

Comment: this however loses the focus on modularization as for other  actions potentially using saveUser and addUser methods you would have to redefine them again.

Comment: @lombausch Potentially, but these functions appear to be dedicated for use with `signIn`.

Comment: I tried this, It worked in fisrt instance but then I can't acces to the saveUser function which is called from addUser. I also tryed to declare saveUser in addUser but it didn't work. Have you gout any other trik please?

Comment: @user2113500 `addUser` can call `saveUser` but it was called as `SaveUser` in your original code.  The casing needs to match.  I've just updated the answer with that.

Comment: You rock! and I need a new glasses.

Answer (score 0):

Either go with callbacks, or pass any in-scope variables as extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a first parameter to e.g `saveUser` and bind it to res:

```
function saveUser(res, err, users){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send("Not inserted");

    }else{
            console.log(user);
            console.log('registered!');
            res.send("OKish");
    }
}
```

and then

```
user.save(saveUser.bind(null,res));
```

Comment: could you please elaborate I can't get this working. thank you!